# Problem with IV inheritance and Destiny Knot

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I'm sorry about asking so many questions for this game but the technical stuff really mess with my head! So, I got a 6IV Ditto from a Reddit giveaway and I asked a dumb question about how to get a 6IV Ralts but here is a different question about it:

I have a 6IV Gligar and 6IV Ditto. I make the Jolly Ditto hold an Everstone while my Gligar holds the Destiny Knot.

Destiny Knot is meant to guarantee that 5IVs pass down but I still get 3-4IV Pokemon and it really takes up so much time so... What's wrong with the breeding? Is it the Destiny Knot?

Comment: And a subquestion: Is there a timespan as to the questions we ask? For example, I asked this question now, but am I not allowed to ask again until an hour? And one more thing: Can we put in more than one question into one post?

Comment: I believe there's a hard limit of the number of questions you can ask.  That's at 50 questions over a 30 day period.  As for adding multiple questions to the same question, so long as they're asking about the same area, that's usually OK, but we will actively prune additional questions if they're not related.  Or just close the question.

Comment: I'm assuming that you're using an IV calculator to find the IVs of the resulting babies, can you post the values it's giving you?

Comment: Any chance you could post some screenshots?

Comment: ^I second that. Specifically, can you get a screenshot of the ditto and ralts' stats at level 50? Use the [Battle Institute](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Battle_Institute) to temporarily raise/lower their levels, and check their summaries in-battle. Just Save outside, enter a battle, screenshot the summary screen and restart the game :)

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible, if you have both parents with 6IV and you are using Destiny Knot you will have offspring with at least 5IV. This means that Ditto or Gligar isn't a flawless pokemon.
What does the IV-checker say about them?

Comment: The IV checker says that they have relatively superior potential and then he tells me that they have 3-4 really good stats about them which is the IVs that are maxed.

Comment: Yes, but you are saying they have 6 maxed IVs, so the IV checker should tell you that every stat is the best, and that "They simply can't be beat! That's how I judge it." If him tells you that they have only 3-4 really good stats they're clearly not 6IV.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say that I go to check my Gligar and he says that every stat cant be beat and its the same with the Ditto. If it wasn't like that, I wouldnt be asking this question :( I answered as 3-4IVs because I thought you were asking about what the IV checker says about the offspring

Comment: @AmirSha Are you REALLY sure that both Ditto and Gligar have each IV maxed? Because it's not possible that you don't get a 5IV child using Destiny Knot.

Comment: I am **ABSOLUTELY** sure. The IV checker tells me that theyre both at 6IVs